# What does affine invariance mean in the context of the Newton's method?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, affine-geometry

The textbook Numerical Solution of Boundary Value Problems for Ordinary Differential Equations (by Ascher, Mattheij, and Russell) states on [page 329](https://books.google.de/books?id=0RvOrnO4WgwC&lpg=PA329&dq=newton%20method%20affine%20invariant&pg=PA329#v=onepage&q=newton%20method%20affine%20invariant&f=false):

> [W]e observe  that Newton's method  is *affine  invariant*; i. e., if $$\hat{f}(s)=Bf(s)$$ where $B$  is a constant,  nonsingular matrix, then Newton's  method  yields  precisely  the same  sequence  of  iterates  for  the  two  functions  $f$ and  $\hat{f}$.  (Note  that  $f$ and  $\hat{f}$  have the same  zeroes.)

And I've seen pretty much the same definition of *affine invariance* in other texts.

I get the *invariance* part: $$\hat{f'}(s)^{-1}\hat{f}(s)=(Bf'(s))^{-1}Bf(s)=f(s)^{-1}f(s).$$ But if $B$ is any non-singular matrix, what is so *affine* about it? E.g. if we compose $f$ with a translation, then it doesn't seem to work anymore. Why do we call the invariance *affine*?

Comment: Perhaps it means an invariance with respect to *some* affine transformations.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: I thought it must be taken out of context since calling it affine invariant simply because every isomorphism is also an affine function doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I've seen the same terminology used in several other texts on Newton's method.  I think perhaps "affine" lingers because there is both affine covariance and affine contravariance (both inputs and outputs).  For instance, if I transform $s=Mt+t_0$ where $M$ is invertible, then the Newton steps transform in the same way: $\Delta s = M\Delta t$.